# difference -in "Create databse" and "create database if not exists"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is the actual difference between "**CREATE DATABASE database_name**" and "**CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database_name"?**

Comment: second is Re-runable script. Which will not throw error how many times execute it unlike the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database_name` will execute the `CREATE DATABASE database_name` only if the `database_name` does not already exist.

If the `database_name` does not exit, both queries will do the same job, that is they create the `database_name`.

If the `database_name` exits, `CREATE DATABASE database_name` will return an error similar to "the database 'database_name' already exists", while `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database_name` will not return an error (it simply does nothing).

When you write a script (let's say you create the database, then create tables, then insert some data), you don't want the execution to stop just because the database exits, so you use the second query.

Answer (score 0):

only one thing:

> An error occurs if the database exists and you did not specify IF NOT
>   EXISTS.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html

so basically for : error management.